# TFS Work Item WHEN and WHEN (IF and IF) conditions

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

Is there any way to implement a field RULE involving satisfaction of multiple conditions?

e.g. FIELD A is REQUIRED, IF FIELD 1 value is "value" AND IF FIELD 2 value is "foo".

I currently have 2 WHEN conditions for the field, however it applies the OR logic, so any satisfied condition between the two, the field is set to required.

Any hopes on implementing this one through a work around? Or am I missing an existing solution already?

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?